# How do I make an application manually extracted from a .tar be available on "Show Applications"?

Tags: gnome-shell, menu, .desktop, tar, appmenu

I want my application that is portable extract from a .tar, like PopcornTime to be available in the "Show applications" in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04).

I extract my application in some folder and to run it, i used to run

```
./folder/'ApplicationRunnable'
```

I realize that is a lot easier to click on icon, that i created by using to following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

But in my "Show Application" search, my application can't be found...

How can I make this kind of application appears on my "Show Applications" search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a .desktop file copy it into `~/.local/share/applications`.

If not, see [this guide on how to create one.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Answer (score 3):

**In general** you need to create a `.desktop` launcher for the application in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory.

To create a simple `.desktop` launcher by hand, first create an empty text file, name it `<application-name>.desktop`, and add the following lines to it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application Name
Comment=A short description of the application
Exec=/full/path/to/'ApplicationRunnable'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/icon-file
```

Then save the file. If it doesn't appear in '*Show Applications*', log out and re-login.

**In particular** if you already have a *working* `.desktop` launcher (created with the GUI tool `gnome-desktop-item-edit`) in your `~/Desktop`, then just copy it to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the .desktop file generated with gnome-desktop-item-edit in /usr/share/applications